# Google_Maps_V3_API Geo Location Issue

Tags: codeigniter

There is Some issue with code and not getting geo location through this library

$this->load->library('googlemaps');

```
        $config = array();
        $config['center'] = 'auto';
        $config['onboundschanged'] = 'if (!centreGot) {
        var mapCentre = map.getCenter();
        marker_0.setOptions({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(mapCentre.lat(), mapCentre.lng()) 
        });
        }
        centreGot = true;';


        $this->googlemaps->initialize($config);

        // set up the marker ready for positioning 
        // once we know the users location
        $marker = array();
        $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);
        $data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();
```

Comment: What would the issue be?

Comment: not showing the current location

Comment: $config['onboundschanged'] = 'if (!centreGot) {
        var mapCentre = map.getCenter();
        marker_0.setOptions({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(mapCentre.lat(), mapCentre.lng()) 
        });
        }
        centreGot = true;';

here is some issue

Comment: As i want to get my current location i have used Google_Maps_V3_API but when i am trying to get my location its not working other vise it working fine

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You'll want to be much more clear on what the result you expect is, what the exact behavior you're currently getting, what if any server or console errors you're getting (please check), and enough code for us to replicate the issue on our computers.

Comment: when i pass onboundschanges to config that give me the current location as documentations says but there when i pass it maps have no display just a gray screen with no error message.